# How to set up 'resolvers' to get the latest ScalaTest automatically?

Tags: sbt, scalatest

I'm running Scala 2.9.2 and ScalaTest 2.0M4. I have a local copy of the ScalaTest jar and would now like to get it automatically from a repo.

[Scalatest site](http://www.scalatest.org/download#20m4) says this about it:

```
..is available [at] the Sonatype OSS Maven repository (which is mirrored on the central Maven repository as well):

group id: org.scalatest
artifact id: scalatest_2.9.0 (for Scala 2.9.0+)
version: 2.0.M4
Or via sbt (version 0.10 or higher) with:

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.0.M4" % "test"
```

Now, what 'resolvers' must I add to my 'project/plugins.sbt' to reach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it to work with this:

In `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
resolvers += "SonaType" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public"
```

In `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "latest.integration" % "test"
```

What I do not get is that adding 'in Test' after 'libraryDependencies' does not work but gives:

```
object scalatest is not a member of package org
```

Well, I'll leave it here. If someone knows why 'in Test' is unwelcome here, give a line. Thanks.